# Does EOS DB support text-based queries?

Tags: database

Can I query a table with an indexed string column a la SQL?

Is something like this possible for example:

```
SELECT * from <table_name> where <my_string_column> LIKE '%test%';
```

Comment: I see the `get` and `find` actions in the DB documentation, both working on primary key, but I don't see anything like the example above.

Comment: A use case would be searching for a user by name in a social network.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use an iterator and go row by row using custom code to do the check. Something like this:

```
string test = "test";
for (auto itr = idx.begin(); itr != idx.end(); ++itr) {
    if (itr->username.find(test) != std::string::npos) {
        // Do something with that user and then exit the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Since the database tables are stored on RAM, this should run pretty quickly, but if there are too many rows you could end up hitting the transaction time limit, so I would recommend filtering first using the index to reduce the amount of rows that you would iterate through, like limiting it to only users of a certain type, or something like that. You can use `lower_bound` for that, for example ([documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#lower_bound)).

Besides that, EOSIO allows separating the stored data in different `scopes`, so you might want to have users of one particular type or country or some other property stored under separate scopes, and that way each table would be smaller as well.